# Refresh page using Cron after any post is published

Tags: cron

I would like to refresh page after any post(custom post type) is published, how do I refresh page using the Cron after any post is published? Can anybody tell me in which direction should I go? I ve'been trying to google that info, but it seems that nobody were ever interested or it seems as impossible.

Comment: What do you mean by "refresh page"? Do you mean refresh like when you hit F5 in your browser?

Comment: Yes, exactly, but not browser, but server side, in order for the people who visits the site and remain there inactive can see that new post were published, I want to set up post counter to let them know that etc.Most of sites has scheduled cron to refresh the site every 5 minutes, I think that also this site behave the same, that's nice for people to see that they have a new respond without F5ing, on my website is useless to refresh site every 5 minutes, I don't have big traffic there, I have 5 -20 submitted posts a day, so I would like to refresh that site 5-20 times depending on submissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't think you can do this with cron.

Browser sends request to server and gets response. It isn't connected permanently to your server. So if you want to refresh page which is already displayed in browser, you have to force browser to send request for this page one more time (do refresh).

Another way would be placing some JS on your page. It could send AJAX request every few minutes (or so) to your server and check if there is anything new to show and process them in any way you'd like.

Comment: I understand and thanks for your respond, but if I will force JS to make requests every few minutes I can directly setup the cron to refresh every few minutes that page, I wanted to avoid to do something more frequently, I thought that there exists some code which trigger the server to refresh the site NOW because there were submitted post, custom post, comment.

Comment: How would you refresh page with cron? Cron works only on server side - you are not able to make my browser to do anything with cron...

If you want to do it now (not with request) you will have to use some AJAX Push Engine but it won't be so easy. And it has nothing to do with cron...

Comment: I see now, you are right, cron has nothing to do with that, Ajax looks to be a right answer, I will study this way how to do it now, thanks for pointing me to the right direction.